# Java, создать папку Win10

Tags: java, файловая-система

Здравствуйте. Программе нужно хранить свои ресурсы в какой-либо папке. Для этого она должна ее создать, так вот проблема в том, что на моем компьютере программа создает любую папку без ограничений, а при запуске этой же программы на другом компьютере (win8 и выше), она не может создать никакую папку из-за ограничений по безопасности (как я понял) windows

Как можно обойти это ограничение? Или где нужно создавать папку, чтобы этого ограничения не было?

Comment: запускайте программу от имени админестратора

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте папку с ресурсами вот тут:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

Comment: так и делал, прописывал путь через user.home, однако, на чужом компьютере такой способ не катит

Comment: @Schepalin почему же?